# PHP SQL won't update the data

Tags: php, html, sql-update

Update as of 23rd June 2015

The update query still not working. Took an advice from Rene Kross and made some code cleanup and stumbled upon a few part missing semicolons and etc however the update query are still not working.

Here's the adminUpdate.php

```html
<?php 
 
 require 'Connect.php';

 $staffID = null;
 if ( !empty($_GET['staffID'])) {
  $staffID = $_REQUEST['staffID'];
 }
 
 if ( null==$staffID ) {
  header("Location: ManageAdministrator.php");
 }
 
 if ( !empty($_POST)) {
  // keep track validation errors
  
  $adminNameError = null;
  $emailError = null;
  $SKGError = null;
  $ExtnError = null;
  

  // keep track post values
  
  $adminName = $_POST['adminName'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $SKG = $_POST['SKG'];
  $Extn = $_POST['Extn'];
  

  // validate input
  $valid = true;
  
  if (empty($adminName)){
   $adminNameError = "Please enter Administrator Name";
   $valid = false;
  }
  
  if (empty($email)) {
   $emailError = 'Please enter Email Address';
   $valid = false;
  } else if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
   $emailError = 'Please enter a valid Email Address';
   $valid = false;
  }
  
  if (empty($SKG)) {
   $SKGError = 'Please choose SKG';
   $valid = false;
  }
  if(empty($Extn)){
   $ExtnError = "Please enter Extension Number";
   $valid = false;
  }
  
  
  // update data
  if ($valid) {
   $pdo = Database::connect();
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $sql = "UPDATE admin set adminName ='$adminName', email ='$email', SKG ='$SKG', Extn ='$Extn' WHERE staffID = '$staffID'";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array($staffID,$adminName,$email,$SKG,$Extn));
   Database::disconnect();
   header("Location: ManageAdministrator.php");
  }
 } else {
  $pdo = Database::connect();
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin where staffID = ?";
  $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array($staffID));
  $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $adminName = $data['adminName'];
  $email = $data['email'];
  $SKG = $data['SKG'];
  $Extn = $data['Extn'];
  $password = $data['password'];
  Database::disconnect();
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>Update Administrator</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="Capability Management">
      <!-- CSS External Link -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body>
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


      <div id="wrapper">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
         <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="HomePage.php"><b> Training Log Database </b></a>
          </div>

          <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
                 <li class="dropdown">
                     <!-- PHP REFER LOGIN NAME-->
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> M Farhan M Fazli <b class="caret"></b></a>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="MyProfile.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                           </li>
                           <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li>
                            <!-- PHP LOGOUT FUNCTION -->
                            <a href="LoginPage.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items start here -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="HomePage.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="ManageAdministrator.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Manage Administrator</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <!-- Add new pages here -->
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Manage Staff</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Manage Training<i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="TrainingList.php">Training Information</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">TBA</a>
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i>  Tools for Administrator<i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo1" class="collapse">
                          <li><a href="#"> Add News </a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"> Add Announcement </a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"> Search News</a> </li>
                          <li><a href="#"> Search Announcement </a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"> View My Post </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> FAQs</a>
                    </li>
                
                
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
         <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row col-lg-12">
           <h2 class="page-header"> Update Administrator Account </h2>
           <div class="row col-lg-12">
            <h3> Administrator details </h3>
            <div class="row col-lg-12">

      <form class="form-horizontal form-group" action="adminUpdate.php?id=<?php echo $staffID?>" method="post">

          <!-- <div class="form-group col-lg-12 <?php echo !empty($staffIDError)?'error':'';?>">
            <label>Administrator Staff ID</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="staffID" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($staffID)?$staffID:'';?>">
                <?php if (!empty($staffIDError)): ?>
                  <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $staffIDError;?></span>
                 <?php endif; ?> 
          </div>-->

          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 <?php echo !empty($adminNameError)?'error':'';?>">
            <label>Administrator Name</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="adminName" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($adminName)?$adminName:'';?>">
                <?php if (!empty($adminNameError)): ?>
                  <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $adminNameError;?></span>
                 <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
            <label>Administrator Email</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:'';?>">
                <?php if (!empty($emailError)): ?>
                  <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $emailError;?></span>
                 <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 <?php echo !empty($ExtnError)?'error':'';?>">
           <label> Extension Number </label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Extn" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($Extn)?$Extn:'';?>">
             <?php if (!empty($ExtnError)): ?>
              <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $ExtnError;?></span>
             <?php endif; ?>
           </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 <?php echo !empty($SKGError)?'error':'';?>">
            <label>SKG</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="SKG" value="<?php echo !empty($SKG)?$SKG:'';?>">
                 <option> SKG 09 </option>
                 <option> SKG 18 </option>
                 <option> SKG 20 </option>
                 <option> SKG 16 </option>
                 <option> SKG 11 </option>
                 <option> SKG 13 </option>
                 <option> SKG 14 </option>
                 <option> SKG 12 </option>
                 <option> SKG 15 </option>
                 <option> SKG 10 </option>
                 <option> SKG 25 </option>
                </select>
                <?php if (!empty($SKGError)): ?>
                  <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $SKGError;?></span>
                 <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

         <!-- <div class="form-group col-lg-12 <?php echo !empty($passwordError)?'error':'';?>">
            <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo !empty($password)?$password:'';?>">
                <?php if (!empty($passwordError)): ?>
                  <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $passwordError;?></span>
                 <?php endif; ?> -->
          </div>

        <div class="form-actions col-lg-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="ManageAdministrator.php">Back</a>
          </div>
        
     </form>

            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--wrap--> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Here's the Connect.php

```html
<?php
class Database 
{
 private static $dbName = 'tlad' ; 
 private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
 private static $dbUsername = 'root';
 private static $dbUserPassword = '';
 
 private static $cont  = null;
 
 public function __construct() {
  exit('Init function is not allowed');
 }
 
 public static function connect()
 {
    // One connection through whole application
       if ( null == self::$cont )
       {      
        try 
        {
          self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);  
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
          die($e->getMessage());  
        }
       } 
       return self::$cont;
 }
 
 public static function disconnect()
 {
  self::$cont = null;
 }
}
?>
```

Here's my table:
[image]

As I mentioned earlier, the read, create and delete function are working except for this update function aren't.

Please note: I've followed a tutorial on creating a CRUD datatable, while his template worked but my code aren't. Here's the tutorial's code for update template:

```html
<?php 
 
 require 'database.php';

 $id = null;
 if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
 }
 
 if ( null==$id ) {
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
 
 if ( !empty($_POST)) {
  // keep track validation errors
  $nameError = null;
  $emailError = null;
  $mobileError = null;
  
  // keep track post values
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
  
  // validate input
  $valid = true;
  if (empty($name)) {
   $nameError = 'Please enter Name';
   $valid = false;
  }
  
  if (empty($email)) {
   $emailError = 'Please enter Email Address';
   $valid = false;
  } else if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
   $emailError = 'Please enter a valid Email Address';
   $valid = false;
  }
  
  if (empty($mobile)) {
   $mobileError = 'Please enter Mobile Number';
   $valid = false;
  }
  
  // update data
  if ($valid) {
   $pdo = Database::connect();
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $sql = "UPDATE customers  set name = ?, email = ?, mobile =? WHERE id = ?";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array($name,$email,$mobile,$id));
   Database::disconnect();
   header("Location: index.php");
  }
 } else {
  $pdo = Database::connect();
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers where id = ?";
  $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array($id));
  $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $name = $data['name'];
  $email = $data['email'];
  $mobile = $data['mobile'];
  Database::disconnect();
 }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    
       <div class="span10 offset1">
        <div class="row">
         <h3>Update a Customer</h3>
        </div>
      
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
       <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($nameError)?'error':'';?>">
         <label class="control-label">Name</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:'';?>">
            <?php if (!empty($nameError)): ?>
             <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $nameError;?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
         <label class="control-label">Email Address</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:'';?>">
            <?php if (!empty($emailError)): ?>
             <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $emailError;?></span>
            <?php endif;?>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($mobileError)?'error':'';?>">
         <label class="control-label">Mobile Number</label>
         <div class="controls">
            <input name="mobile" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($mobile)?$mobile:'';?>">
            <?php if (!empty($mobileError)): ?>
             <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $mobileError;?></span>
            <?php endif;?>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
        <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code here. Not as link to a git repository.

Comment: And how are you sure it doesn't show an error? Are you checking for errors? What's the go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `execute` has 5 parameters, but query wants 6.

```
$sql = "UPDATE admin  set staffID = ?, adminName = ?, email = ?, SKG = ?, Extn = ?  WHERE staffID = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($staffID, $adminName, $email, $SKG, $Extn, $staffID));
```

Also were missing `$` in front of `email`, `SKG` and `Extn`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, can you give a bit more detailed explanation on the execute 5 parameters and query wants 6 part? I've updated the code by adding password also into the list. where right now it will give a control to update all 6 columns. I'm very sorrry, I'm trying to learn by the way...

Comment: You added 5 parameters, what replace `?` in `SET` part, but it didn't have `$staffID` for 6th `?` in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Kross : Nope it didn't, however Rene, I've updated my post so you may view the problem in details. As of on post, the code for the update template are working but my code aren't but when I replace it with my custom table, it didn't worked.